# Is there a list of available swag?

Tags: support, swag

I got friendly mail from you after reaching a quarter million rep, sending me to a Google form where I am promised "something very special created for you". No spoilers about that please.

You also kindly offer *"anything else"* and I wonder what the options are? An email reply got lost somehow. Is there a list of available SO swag somewhere?

Comment: congratulations

Comment: If you get \[spoiler\] or \[spoiler\], I will be very jelly!

Comment: I'm also waiting for my 0.000064 million swag.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I think you meant `0.064` million swag :-)

Comment: Only another 150 years to go before I qualify!

Comment: Something very special? Hm, I was promised "*a little something for a loved one or friend who's been patient while I was giving so much*".

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm embarrassed now.

Comment: @MarounMaroun stop using floats. ;)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, there's not. There's not an easy way of accessing a list of everything in our inventory from the service we use, so maintaining a public list of everything we have would be very manual work that no one wants to do.

But aside from that, the text box isn't meant as a "pick out the exact item from our inventory" type of thing. It's meant to be a free form thing where hey, maybe we just happen to have something like that. But also gives us an idea of what our high-reputation users might like to see. If a bunch of people are requesting a USB flash drive, then maybe that's something we'd be interested in producing in the future. Creating random new things to send out to users for a while is fun, but creating things the users *actually want* is even more fun.

Most users leave it blank, and some use it to request swag for other sites they participate at, have seen their swag, and just like it a lot.

Comment: Yes, I'd love to get an overflow-themed USB drive!

Comment: @Bergi Maybe sized at 7GB, 15GB or 31GB for good measure.

Comment: superyacht with an SO logo would be a great incentive

Comment: I want a 1TB SO hard drive.

Comment: I have a red Red Hat hat.  You need to think of something as cool and meta as that!

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 Like a StackOverflow themed Jenga game?

Comment: @Lithium  Oooh, not bad.  But I think we can do better.  StackOverflow playing cards?  StackOverflow blackjack dealing shoe?  StackOverflow magazine rack?  StackOverflow stack rack?  Hmm.....

Comment: StackOverflow themed Operation.

Comment: I've got it...  StackOverflow stacking cups!  When you feel like being meta, you can always fill them with a beverage until they overflow!

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 But don't stacking cups usually have holes in the bottom so the air doesn't prevent them from ... wait, that actually makes them perfect to send to people to fill with liquid, never mind. I didn't say a thing.

Comment: Can I have an inbox that has orange colored rectangles suspended haphazardly above it?

Comment: While we're doing a wish list - I'd love a SO mug *without* the corny `if coffee drink coffee else fill coffee`. It would be super elegant. Also, thanks for giving things!

Comment: I demand all swag be unicorn-themed!

Comment: So if enough people fill in "unicorn paintings" yer going to send out unicorn paintings?

Comment: @Lithium "A Stack Overflow themed Jenga game" is a pretty good metaphor for how most software development works 

Comment: Would you consider SO-themed underwear with the logo on the backside? I'm asking for someone else...

Comment: Let me guess who received a clock labelled S`<spoiler>` Overflow